# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_encode()

Tags: php, json

I got a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_encode()" on my php file which is hosted on an ovh server. Here is the code:

```
function get_paypload_giftcard($partnerId, $gcRequestId, $currencyCode, $gcAmount)
{
    $amount = trim($gcAmount);
    $payload = array(
    "creationRequestId" => $gcRequestId,
    "partnerId" => $partnerId,
    "value" =>
    array(
        "currencyCode" => $currencyCode,
        "amount" => floatval($amount)
    )
    );
    return json_encode($payload); 
}
```

How to solve the problem? 
Is there any other alternative than json_encode?

Comment: what version of PHP? Is the json PHP extension installed and enabled? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php lists the pre-requisites for using the function. And http://php.net/manual/en/json.setup.php shows how to get it working. Normally it's installed by default in PHP 5.2 and up. So presumably either your PHP version is ancient, or it's been disabled on purpose for some reason.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: yeah the version was the problem its solve now ty

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` requires php >= 5.2.  It sounds like you're server is running something earlier than that (you can check your php version with the `phpversion()`) function.

Assuming that is the case, you'll need to use a library that mimics the functionality.  A quick google search indicates there are [bunch](https://boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html) [of](https://gist.github.com/jorgeatorres/1239453) [these](http://pecl.php.net/package/json).

Using the one from https://boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

```
function get_paypload_giftcard($partnerId, $gcRequestId, $currencyCode, $gcAmount)
{
    require_once '/path/to/jsonwrapper.php';

    $amount = trim($gcAmount);
    $payload = array(
    "creationRequestId" => $gcRequestId,
    "partnerId" => $partnerId,
    "value" =>
    array(
        "currencyCode" => $currencyCode,
        "amount" => floatval($amount)
    )
    );
    return json_encode($payload); 
}
```

Since this library just checks for the existence of the builtin function and adds it if it is missing it should work after requiring it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i updated the php version to 5.6 on the OVH server